# Jquery toggle switch on/off state with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, switch-statement, toggle

I'm currently trying to get the state "on" or "off" from this jquery plugin https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.onoff working on my Wordpress but without any success.

I would like tu use it to make some conditions for toggle on/off filters, here the link of my wordpress http://www.capitainebar.com/recherche/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just get the status of the checkbox like you would with a normal checkbox:

```
$('#onoffswitch1').val();
```

would be the solution in your wordpress link.

If you want to do an action if it the value is checked or not:

```
if ($('#onoffswitch1').is(":checked")){
  // it is checked
}
```